# NotWritablePropertyException - When context is initialized - Spring

Tags: java, spring

This is quite a common question in spring community. However even after referring many suggestions and answers, I couldn't get the below program to work correctly.

I need to inject a property of String type in Spring bean.

**Here is the bean definition:**

```
<bean id="AzoneMessageTransformer" class="com.test.wsg.RequestMessageTransformer">      
    <property name="converAndMarshal" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="BzoneMessageTransformer" class="com.test.wsg.RequestMessageTransformer">
    <property name="converAndMarshal" value="false" />
    <property name="authCode" >
        <value>BZ</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Here is the Spring bean:**

```
public class RequestMessageTransformer implements InitializingBean {

    private String authCode = null;

    private boolean converAndMarshal = true;

    public void setConverAndMarshal(boolean converAndMarshal) {
        this.converAndMarshal = converAndMarshal;
    }

    public boolean isConverAndMarshal() {
        return converAndMarshal;
    }

    public void setAuthCode(String authCode) {
        this.authCode = authCode;
    }

    public String getAuthCode() {
        return authCode;
    }

    }
```

**Receiving the below error when context is getting initialized:**

```
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'authCode' of bean class [com.test.wsg.RequestMessageTransformer]: Bean property 'authCode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:926)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
```

Any help and suggestions for pointing out my mistake is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: @Mahesh version used : 4.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: by the you are implementing intializing bean where is the implementation of  afterPropertiesSet() method. you would have the class compiled in first place

Answer (score 0):

authCode is string property, you should set property something like this

```
<bean id="BzoneMessageTransformer" class="com.test.wsg.RequestMessageTransformer">
    <property name="converAndMarshal" value="false" />
    <property name="authCode" value="BZ" />        

</bean>
```

Comment: tried this option which is a short-cut alternative to a nested "<value>...</value>"...but still facing the same error.